# Which one is faulty - PSU, GPU, DVI-D to VGA adapter or the Motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu, troubleshooting, lenovo-desktop-computer

I bought a Radeon RX 460 and I get an inescapable screen freeze when switching to another program with Alt + Tab.

This issue does not occur when I underclock the GPU with MSI afterburner to 50% of its stock frequency.

One thing I've noticed in HWInfo is that my GPU VRM Voltage is 11.755V on average, and drops down to 11.266V under full load. I know that the software readings can be inaccurate, but I don't have any other way to measure those values.

So, my question is - how to figure out what should I replace - the PSU, the GPU, the Mobo, or something else?

PC: Lenovo M83 mid tower format with an Intel i5-4590, PSU is
AC Bell PCB005 (280W - M83 stock PSU), and 4 x 2Gb of ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSU, first guess.

I'd be looking at at least a 450W for that, if not more just to be on the safe side.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to ask here as well because it's going to be a real chore to find a 24-pin to 14-pin adapter for Lenovo motherboards, so I wanted more eyes on this before starting the journey of finding said adapter.